# Service wscsvc failed to start while Installing Biztalk 2010 Developer Tools

Tags: windows-services, biztalk, biztalk-2010

While installing Biztalk Server 2010 (developer tools and documentation only), received the following error.

"Error 1920.Service wscsvc (wscsvc) failed to start. Verify 
that you have sufficient privileges to start system services."

This causes the install to roll back, as it is not possible to merely ignore and continue.

Windows 7 EE, running as administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was wscsvc is not installed, or has been removed, on my build, probably by IT.  Since the Biztalk installer did not offer to bypass, I was faced with either trying to modify the setup (Orca or other tool), getting Windows Security Center installed, or the option I selected.

I ended up writing and installing a Windows Service and naming it wscsvc.

Biztalk Server 2010 setup was happy that it could stop wscsvc, and ran without a problem.